# How to combine a Bootstrap btn-group with an HTML form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Using Bootstrap 3.x, the following produces a drop down menu.  I need a dropdown menu that behaves like an HTML form, with a (predetermined) value for each item in the dropdown.  How can I combine these 2 things to get the functionality of an HTML form with the style of a Bootstrap btn-group?

```
<!-- Single button -->
<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
    Action <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <form>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: sorry. front end web development isnt my typical thing.  how do you suggest i post a demo for this?   Thanks!

Comment: You setup one on [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/)

Comment: cool - here's an example. http://jsbin.com/IgefUyoS/4/

Answer (score 5):

You could do something like this..

http://bootply.com/103058

```
<!-- Single button -->
<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
    Action <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <form>
       <div class="form-group">
         <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail1" placeholder="Email">
       </div>
       <div class="form-group">
         <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
       </div>
       <div class="form-group">
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Sign in</button>
       </div>
    </form>
  </ul>
```

And use jquery to prevent the dropdown from closing on click..

```
$('.dropdown-menu>form').click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```